# Should I correct for bias and set a delta degree of freedom when dealing with a finite data set?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, bias, degrees-of-freedom

I'm analysing data from a suite of tests. The tests are effectively sanity/pass-off checks for control SW which is being developed: each test follows the same procedure and I don't expect great variation in the results. Some variability will be there as the testing is performed on a real-world system which is effected by environmental conditions.

My reasoning is that I don't need to correct for bias or delta degree of freedom for variability as I am dealing with an entire population of results to get an idea of what is an acceptable variation in values and what should be considered an outlier. I may be wrong though as statistical analysis is not a field I have had great experience in.

Going forward I intend to compare future test results to the ones I am using here as a "baseline".